# Add document to ektron throught API

Tags: ektron

I would like to add document to ektron through API in check in state. when I execute add method ,document goes to publish state. How I can save it on check in state

```
Ektron.Cms.Framework.Core.Content.Content _content = new Ektron.Cms.Framework.Core.Content.Content();
                contentData = _content.GetItem(docId);
                contentData.LanguageId = langId;
                contentData.Html = html;
                _content.Add(contentData);
                contentAPI.CheckInContentById(docId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try applying an approval chain to the folder where you are adding documents.  This will set all content to a "submitted" (S) state where it won't be "approved" (A) until a valid user approves it.

Submitted content cannot be viewed publically until approved so this may meet your requirements.